# Determine if a matrix is an orthogonal projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, idempotents, projection-matrices

We define an orthogonal projection as a linear transformation that maps a vector into its orthogonal projection in some (given ahead) subspace $W$. Let's call the matrix of that transformation (relative to the standard basis) the orthogonal projection matrix.

Now, suppose I have a matrix $Q$.

> Is there a way to determine if $Q$ is an orthogonal projection matrix?

I mean, we can check if $Q^2=Q$ and check if $\text{Null}(Q) \perp \text{Col}(Q)$. Is that sufficient to conclude that $Q$ is a projection matrix?

Comment: You may want to see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)), in particular the second point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Projection_matrix). (So basically check that $Q^T = Q$ and $Q^2 = Q$, i.e. $Q$ is *symmetric and idempotent*.) You may also want to see the comments [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections) regarding your question of the null space and column space of $Q$.

Comment: Thank you @MinusOne-Twelfth.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with $W:=\operatorname{Col}(Q)$ we have for every $v$,
$$ Q(Qv-v)=Q^2v-Qv=0,$$
hence $Qv-v\in\ker Q\subseteq W^\perp$, of course $Qv\in W$, and for $v\in W$ we have $Qv=v$.